# Entity Framework: Can I set a custom name for a Navigation Property in SQL Server to be used when generating from the database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Anyone know if I can setup something in SQL Server that Entity Framework will read when setting up Foreign Key Navigation properties?

My Issue: I have a table call "SurveyEntry" with a child table called "SurveyInvite"

I have 2 FK setup from the Invite to the Entry table - one for parent (what orignal entry the invite was created from) and one nullable for what "Entry" is completed related to the invite...

When I generate the EDMX - it creates two Navigation Properties:
SurveyEntry and SurveyEntry1

I renamed the 2nd to "CompletedEntry" to make sense in code.

But if I have to re-build the EDMX (early stages of dev, will be adding must more stuff and will probably blow it out and completely rebuild it a few times) - I don't want to have to remember to go in and re-name the property whenever I do that - I'm sure I will forgot it sometime!

Tried to use the Description value in SQL in the Field and FK relationship, no luck - if not possible, sure would be nice to have this as a feature...

Comment: Why a complete rebuild? If you just update the model from the database EF will keep your renamed navigation properties unchanged.

Comment: Update is fine for when you have minor changes, but I find that if you are making major changes to the database, removing fields/tables, add/remove FK relationships etc - the "refresh" misses a lot of those changes - easy enough to just completely re-build the edmx - takes less than a minute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaningful Names for Navigation Properties using Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313991/meaningful-names-for-navigation-properties-using-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1):

EF doesn't support this way of customizing the model generation.

However since you are in the early stages of development consider using a different workflow when making changes. When you need to change something in the database change the model first, then generate the DDL script from it.

Note that it is possible to customize the generated script, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/11/05/model-first-with-the-entity-framework-4.aspx