# Database first - EF created objects ignoring the name of foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-database-first

I have created a mssql database and then used [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj200620) to create the datamodel. I have noticed something weird and it is also something which doesn't allow me to work with the model without confusion.

One of my objects is Book. Book contains an id, name, isbn, .. and also references to a Person table, like the author, the editor and the publisher.

the created model contains

```
string name;
int id;
string isbn;
int authorid;
int editorid;
int publisherid;
person person1;
person person2;
person person3;
```

Is there a way to change the names of the persons at creation? Because otherwise it is hard to figure out which person is who and I will have to change a lot manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaningful Names for Navigation Properties using Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313991/meaningful-names-for-navigation-properties-using-entity-framework)

Comment: also [Improve Navigation Property Names When Reverse Engineering A Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937193/improve-navigation-property-names-when-reverse-engineering-a-database)